# Change the Background of an ELEMENT within a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've looked online and found some topics related to my issue, although being new to XAML and WPF, i'm having trouble making what I want work.

I have a custom TimeLineControl StackPanel that contains 'Items' of type TimeLineFunctionControl, where the Items uses a DataTemplate to define how the 'Items' are displayed.

```
  <!-- Static Resource = BgColor -->
  <Color R="255" G="255" B="255" A="180" x:Key="BgColor" />

  <!-- Static Resource = BgBrush -->
  <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource BgColor}" x:Key="BgBrush" />

  <!-- DataTemplate = TimeLineFunctionDataTemplate -->
  <DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type tt:FunctionDataType}" 
                 x:Key="TimeLineFunctionDataTemplate">
     <Border x:Name="DataContainer"
        BorderThickness="0.3"
        BorderBrush="Black" 
        CornerRadius="2" 
        Margin="0,20,0,10" 
        Height="50" 
        Background="{DynamicResource BgBrush}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=StartTime.TotalMilliseconds, StringFormat={}{0} ms}" FontSize="8"/>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=EndTime.TotalMilliseconds, StringFormat={}{0} ms}" FontSize="8"/>
        </StackPanel>
     </Border>
  </DataTemplate>

public class FunctionDataType : ITimeLineDataItem
{
    public TimeSpan? StartTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? EndTime { get; set; }
    public Boolean TimelineViewExpanded { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to change the Background color of the Border (DataContainer) dynamically from within the code.

I've tried the following;

**1** - Doesn't work, I've since learnt that once a Template is applied, the Background property is no longer used.

```
titem.Background = (Brush)FindResource("BgBrushTriggered");
```

**2** - Works, although I need to have defined two (2) DataTemplate in XAML, each with different Background colors, seems there must be a better way to do it.

```
titem.ContentTemplate = (DataTemplate)FindResource("TimeLineFunctionDataTriggeredTemplate");
```

**3** - Works, although it changes ALL the items, since i'm changing the DynamicResource value.

```
this.Resources["BgBrush"] = new SolidColorBrush((Color)FindResource("BgColorTriggered"));
```

**4** - Doesn't work, XAML reports "The member "Background" is not recognized or is not accessible";

```
Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"


Background="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"
```

**Q: What are my options?**

**Q: Is there a good online resource to correctly learn XAML and now to apply bindings, styles, templates etc...**

Comment: You could but the colour as a property on the FunctionDataType class. Then just modify that property when you wanted a different colour. You'll need to put a "Inotifypropertychanged" interface on that class though, so that your "change" can be "seen"/notified. You can specify the "colour" of your brush using a string using the # format e.g. "#ffaacc"

Comment: Don't use the code behind, in xaml use `Style` to change the appearance of the `Border` and if your `FunctionDataType` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` then you can use `DataTrigger` in the mentioned `Style` to make it dynamic during runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this would be to bind the `Background` property of the `Border` to a property of the `FunctionDataType` objects and then set this property of the particular item you want to change.

You could either bind directly to a `Brush` property or define some other type of property and use a converter to convert this value into a `Brush`. The FunctionDataType must implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface for this to work.

Please refer to the following sample code.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type tt:FunctionDataType}" 
              x:Key="TimeLineFunctionDataTemplate">
    <Border x:Name="DataContainer"
        BorderThickness="0.3"
        BorderBrush="Black" 
        CornerRadius="2" 
        Margin="0,20,0,10" 
        Height="50" 
        Background="{Binding BgBrush}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=StartTime.TotalMilliseconds, StringFormat={}{0} ms}" FontSize="8"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=EndTime.TotalMilliseconds, StringFormat={}{0} ms}" FontSize="8"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

---

```
public class FunctionDataType : ITimeLineDataItem, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public TimeSpan? StartTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? EndTime { get; set; }
    public Boolean TimelineViewExpanded { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

    private Brush _bgBrush;
    public Brush BgBrush
    {
        get { return _bgBrush; }
        set { _bgBrush = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

---

```
var item = titem.DataContext as FunctionDataType;
item.BgBrush = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a property in your model ItemColorIndex and then bind the background via a converter to it Background="{Binding ItemColorIndex , Converter=XXX}