# How to change Color Inside a Window.Resources C# WPfF

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, binding

I want to change the color of items inside the `Windows.Resources` when click a `Button`.

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Listboxcmmt">
        <Border>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtbox1" Text="{Binding U_Name}" Foreground="#072D55"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

binding to

```xml
<ListBox x:Name="lb_listcmmts" ItemsSource="{Binding Tables[0]}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Listboxcmmt}">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="4"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

I have little Knowledge about Data Binding, wondering if there is a another way.

```
private void Btn_clicked (object ...)
{
    txtbox1.Foreground = Brushes.White;
}
```

Comment: Please include the XAML that use th DataTemplate.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/43649648/1271037

Comment: oh sorry i updated it .

Comment: To do this kind of color change you will either need a binding or a trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I made a `ToggleButton` instead of `Button`.

```xml
<ToggleButton x:Name="btn" Grid.Column="1" Content="Change Color" 
              Width="100" Height="50" Margin="30" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

And in DataTemplate, you have to use `Trigger`.

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Listboxcmmt">
        <Border>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtbox1" Text="{Binding U_Name}" Foreground="#072D55"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=btn, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="txtbox1" Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

#### MainWindow.xaml

```xml
<Window x:Class="ListBoxTriggerSample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListBoxTriggerSample"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Listboxcmmt">
        <Border >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtbox1" Text="{Binding U_Name}" Foreground="#072D55"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=btn, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="txtbox1" Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox x:Name="lb_listcmmts" ItemsSource="{Binding Tables[0]}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Listboxcmmt}">
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="4"/>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.Resources>
        </ListBox>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="btn" Grid.Column="1" Content="Change Color" Width="100" Height="50" Margin="30" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

#### When `ToggleButton` unchecked.

*Foreground="#072D55"*
[image]

#### When `ToggleButton` checked.

*Foreground="Red"*
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hardcoding the colour in the template, you could set the `Foreground` using the `DynamicResource` markup extension and just add another resource that defines the colour:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="foreground" Color="#072D55" />
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Listboxcmmt">
        <Border>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtbox1" Text="{Binding U_Name}" 
                           Foreground="{DynamicResource foreground}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then it's simply a matter of replacing the resource:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Resources["foreground"] = Brushes.White;
}
```